# Is it Possible to compile a Python Source file in Eclipse via Command Prompt?

Tags: java, python, eclipse, cmd

I have been able able to compile a C program in Eclipse which works perfectly. I have installed python interpreter and already set the Environment Variables in Windows.

These are the codes for C. How to modify it to compile a .py(Python) Source File.Thanks

```
public class C_Compile {
public static void main(String args[]){

    String ret = compile();
    System.out.println(ret);

}
    public static String compile()
    {
        String log="";
        String myDirectory = "C:\\";
         try {
             String s= null;
           //change this string to your compilers location
             Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C gcc Hello.c", null, new java.io.File(myDirectory));

         BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
              InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
         boolean error=false;

         log+="";
         while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
             log+=s;
             error=true;
             log+="\n";

         }
         if(error==false) log+="Compilation Successful !!!";

     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
         return log;
    }


  public int runProgram() 
    {
        int ret = -1;
       try
         {            
             Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
             Process proc = rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start a.exe");
             proc.waitFor();
             ret = proc.exitValue();
         } catch (Throwable t)
           {
             t.printStackTrace();
             return ret;
           }
       return ret;                      
    }}
```

Comment: Ok. What exactly are you trying to do? Write an eclipse plugin that runs python programs?

Comment: you dont need to compile python source files, they are interpreted at runtime

Comment: @yurib You can compile them to bytecode though.

Comment: @Cubic Like the program above i just want to get the source code results in the console thats it.

Comment: @Cubid You can but only somewhat rarely need to. (Whenever you'll be deploying your code somewhere the program itself won't have write privileges, like for security reasons.)

Comment: @user2026254 Okay, so what do you have problems with? Remove the compilation step, and in the run step instead of running the compiler output just run `python myfile.py`

Comment: @millimoose can you provide me with a sample.am confuse on how to do it.

Comment: @user2026254 The sample is *your exact code* just change the string you pass to `rt.exec(...)` and call `runProgram()` right away, without calling `compile()`

Comment: What does "in Eclipse via Command Prompt" mean? Do you want to do it in Eclipse or via the Command Prompt? :-/

Comment: @Boann in eclipse..Any help?

Comment: I don't get the point of this at all. This Java program runs *from* the command prompt, right? And it doesn't do anything except run two other commands. You still have to run the Java program, and that's even longer than just pasting `gcc Hello.c && a` (or `python Hello.py`) into a command prompt window.

Answer (score 0):

By default, eclipse doesn't have a python run-time. `Pydev` is a popular plugin for eclipse which provides you with this functionality.

Quoting from [Pydev](http://pydev.org)'s website:

> PyDev is a Python IDE for Eclipse, which may be used in Python, Jython
>   and IronPython development.

However, if you are looking for running this from the command prompt, and have the python environment variable set, you can use the command `python <path>`, where path is the relative/absolute path to a python source file.

Comment: what am looking for is instead of opening cmd in windows and typing the command python <path>, is there any way to perform this in eclipse?

Comment: @user2026254 - Have a look at Pydev's installation manual http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html. It's a plug-in for eclipse which can do this.